# python regex non-greedy forced

Tags: python, regex, non-greedy

I saw an example here about the non-greedy matching.

```
reg_string = "(.*?)>Title"
path = "<html><head><title>Title</title>"
match = re.match(reg_string, path)
if match:
   print match.group()
```

But what if I want to python to yell that this is not matching, because after the first `>` is no `Title`. Because this match:

```
"<html\><head><title>Title"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `reg_string = "([^>]*?)>Title"`

Comment: Works great! Thank you

Comment: @EdaJede please mark this answer as correct if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the BeautifulSoup Python library for more straightforward parsing and handling of HTML:

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you, you want to fetch everything before Title; but if there is no Title text, then it should complain?

```
# Here we add a zero-to-many length match, delimited by `<` or end of line
# and capture it in a second group
reg_string = "(.*?)>(.*?)(<|$)"

path = "<html><head><title>Title</title>"

match = re.match(reg_string, path)
if match:
    if match.group(2) == "":
        throw Exception("No title content")
    else
        print match.group(1)
else:
    throw Exception("No match")
```

Comment: It should complain, when "Title" is not after first ">".

Comment: Then your main example works. Just add an "else" clause, or do `if not match:`